# How to close all "tabs" easily in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs5

How can I close all "tabs" (or windows) easily in Photoshop?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
File > Close All
```

Don't forget to say don't save.

If you have CS4 or higher (maybe earlier too).

```
Hold the shift key down and click one of the X's
```

Comment: Cool. I find it very useful when editing tons of images. I then hover my mouse over the NO button and rapid fire the save as dialog away.

Comment: you can simply hold the "n" button too.